# Question on Kubernetes Jobs and Pod Eviction

Tags: kubernetes-pod

So we had a pod in our Kubernetes cluster on a worker node that repetitively failed a job. I know pods get evicted from worker nodes when nodes crash or have other problems. Is it possible to set up something to evict a pod from a node that repetitively fails a job? I know it would make sense to go look at logs and see why the job failed, but I'm going to ask this question first because management is asking me the question.  I

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure that this is what you are asking for, but, it would probably achieve the result you want if you were to drain the node if a particular job on it keeps failing. That would evict both that job as well as everything else, which might be a bonus considering that you seem to suspect that the job is failing *because* of the node it's on. If this sounds acceptable to you, then you could do the following, which is what my company does (although we have different underlying user stories, it'd be the same setup in the end for you.) It's a two-step process.

1. Write a custom check plugin (basically, a bash script) in [node-problem-detector](https://github.com/kubernetes/node-problem-detector) that would run on each node, check to see if the node is running the job in question, and then look at its failure count, and return a non-0 exit code if the failure count is above whatever you consider acceptable. NPD will then push a status condition to the node (you can read their README for more info on this.)
2. Have something like [draino](https://github.com/planetlabs/draino) automatically drain the node when the status condition appears. (At my company, we found that the official version of draino was missing features and had bugs, so we forked [DataDog's fork](https://github.com/DataDog/draino) of it, tweaked it a bit for our purposes, and are running that. We have not yet submitted the tweaks upstream because honestly we just did a bunch of hacks, I'm sorry to say.)